# App specific filters in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

I have two applications running on different ports of my Tomcat. I have added a filter in my web.xml. This filter class exists in only one of the two applications code/war file. When I start the tomcat, I get  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.filter.MyFilter` 
The result is, application which has filter class runs fine, but other one does not start. My question is : Is there any way to specify application specific filters in Tomcat web.xml so we can load the applications which do not have a particular filter class? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can setup app specific configurations by adding a `web.xml` file in the application's `WEB-INF` folder instead of setting up global configurations by modifying the `XML`s in Tomcat's `conf` folder